# Python data structure where largest element is always kept first

Tags: python, data-structures

I need a data structure like a dict where I can insert elements with a key and then efficiently take out largest element by value when I need it.

Comment: @Firelord I mean, that's just using `heapq`

Comment: In any case, the linked dupicate is for a *sorted list*, which isn't precisely what you are asking, but is that what you are looking for? Otherwise, use a heap. EDIT: I added a duplicate target for a max heap using the `heapq` module in the standard library

Comment: `heapq` is smallest-first, but you can insert tuples like `(-key, item)`